# How to compare variables in a loop, java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have to design a program to simulate players rolling three dice for a number of rounds. Each dice throw is given points. I have to diplay for each round the dice values, and number of points for each player for those values and the **winner of each round** (the player with the highest points for that round, or no-one if they are the same).

I have implemented the points calculator, but I dont know how to display the winner of each round. Also, I am displaying the output vertically when it is supposed to be horizontally.

I think maybe comparing the values inside the loop in the game class may work. P.S. I am new in java, please make any suggestions to change the code if there is a better solution.

**This is waht my program is displaying**

> round 1--> player 1:   2 4 5 points: 11
>
> round 2--> player 1:   2 3 5 points: 10
>
> round 3--> player 1:   2 4 6 points: 12
>
> round 4--> player 1:   4 4 6 points: 34
>
> round 5--> player 1:   3 4 5 points: 52

.

> round 1--> player 2:   3 5 5 points: 33
>
> round 2--> player 2:   3 6 6 points: 35
>
> round 3--> player 2:   2 3 4 points: 49
>
> round 4--> player 2:   1 1 3 points: 25
>
> round 5--> player 2:   1 2 4 points: 7

**This is what it is supposed to display**

> Round 1 Player 1: 1 3 3 points: 27 Player 2: 1 4 5 points: 10 Round winner is player 1
>
> Round 2 Player 1: 1 2 5 points: 8 Player 2: 1 3 6 points: 10 Round winner is player 2
>
> Round 3 Player 1: 1 4 4 points: 29 Player 2: 4 5 6 points: 55 Round winner is player 2
>
> Round 4 Player 1: 1 3 5 points: 9 Player 2: 1 5 5 points: 31 Round winner is player 2
>
> Round 5 Player 1: 3 6 6 points: 35 Player 2: 2 2 4 points: 28 Round winner is player 1
>
> Total wins: Player 1: 2/ Player 2: 3
>
> Total points: Player 1: 108/ Player 2: 134
>
> Average points per round: Player 1: 21.6/ Player 2: 26.8
>
> Overall points winner is player 2.

**Main code**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

  // ------------------- FIELDS ------------------------    
        // Create instance of Scanner class
        public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // variables
        public static ThreeDiceScorer thrdiesc;

        public static int diceArray [];

    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------  
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rounds; // input by user
        int players;  // input by user

        System.out.print("Please input number of rounds (grater or equal than 0) --> ");
        rounds = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print("Please input number of rounds (grater or equal than 0) --> ");
        players = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");

        for (int p = 0; p < players; p++) { //loop for players
        for (int r = 0; r < rounds; r++) {  // loop for number of rounds
        int diceArray [] = new int [3];
        for (int i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++) { // loop for random Array 
        diceArray [i] = 1 + (int)(6 * Math.random());   
        }

        // Create new ThreeDice and calculator instances
        thrdiesc = new ThreeDiceScorer(diceArray [0], diceArray [1], diceArray [2]);


        //Calculate
        thrdiesc.getDie1();
        thrdiesc.getDie2();
        thrdiesc.getDie3();
        thrdiesc.threeSame();
        thrdiesc.runOfThree();
        thrdiesc.pair();
        thrdiesc.allDifferent();
        thrdiesc.calcTotalPoints();
        thrdiesc.printResult(p,r);

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }//end Main Method  
}// end Class
```

**ThreeDice class**

```
public class ThreeDice {
     // ---------------------- ATTRIBUTES ---------------------
     protected int die1;
     protected int die2;
     protected int die3;

     // ------------------ CONSTRUCTOR -------------------
     public ThreeDice(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
          // This puts the three dice values in ascending order.
          int tmp;
          if (s2 < s1) {
              tmp = s2;
              s2 = s1;
              s1 = tmp;
          }
          if (s3 < s2) {
              tmp = s3;
              s3 = s2;
              s2 = tmp;
          }
          if (s2 < s1) {
              tmp = s2;
              s2 = s1;
              s1 = tmp;
          }
          die1 = s1;
          die2 = s2;
          die3 = s3;
     }

     // --------------------- METHODS ---------------------
     // Accessor methods
     public int getDie1() {
          return die1;
     }
     public int getDie2() {
          return die2;
     }
     public int getDie3() {
          return die3;
     }
     public boolean threeSame() {
          return (die1 == die3);
     }
     public boolean runOfThree() {
          return (( (die1 + 1) == die2) && ( (die2 + 1) == die3));
     }
     public boolean pair() {
          return (((die1 == die2) || (die2 == die3)) && (die1 != die3));
     }
     public boolean allDifferent() {
          return (!runOfThree() && (die1 != die2) && (die2 != die3));
     }
     public void printResult() {
          if (threeSame())
              System.out.println("The roll is all the same.");
          else if (runOfThree())
              System.out.println("The roll is a run.");
          else if (pair())
              System.out.println("The roll is a pair.");
          else if (allDifferent())
              System.out.println("The roll is all different.");
    }

}
```

**ThreeDiceScorer (Calculator) Class**

```
public class ThreeDiceScorer extends ThreeDice {
    int total;
     public ThreeDiceScorer(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
         super(s1, s2, s3);
     }
public void calcTotalPoints() {
    int sumOfDice = die1 + die2 + die3;

          if (threeSame()){
              total= sumOfDice + 60;
          }
          else if (runOfThree()){
              total= sumOfDice + 40;
          }
          else if (pair()){
              total= sumOfDice + 20;
          }
          else if (allDifferent()){
            total= sumOfDice;
          }
    }

     public void printResult(int p,int r) {

              System.out.println("round "+ (r+1)+ "--> " + "player "+ (p+1) + "   "+ die1 + " " + die2 + " " + die3 + " " + "points: "+ total);

}
}
```

Comment: Don't delete large (and important) chunks from your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Sol

- Switch player loop and rounds loop.
- In each round loop maintain a max and update it with max value and player.
- Modify printresult a little to remove round.

Loop and max:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < rounds; r++) { // loop for number of rounds
        int max = 0;
        int max_p = 0;
        System.out.println("Round " + r + ": ");
        for (int p = 0; p < players; p++) { //loop for players
            int diceArray[] = new int[3];
            //...
            thrdiesc.printResult(p, r);
            if (thrdiesc.total > max) {
                max = thrdiesc.total;
                max_p = p;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Winner is player " + (max_p + 1) + "\n");
    }
```

PrintResult Method:

```
    public void printResult(int p, int r) {
        System.out.println("player " + (p + 1) + "   " + die1 + " " + die2 + " " + die3 + " " + "points: " + total);
    }
```

## Misc

- Indent Code properly.
- Be careful while copying. (See the prompt)

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I am sorry to bother you again but how could I print the total number of wins, the total number of points , the average points per round, and the overall players winner, I have updated the example. I apriciate your help

Comment: I dobble check the outputs and the code does not work when both values are equal

Comment: It actuallt did work when i ran it.. This shouls be enough to give you direction what tondo nwxt

Answer (score 0):

While looking at your code, I have a feeling you might be able to make this much easier for yourself by creating some simple classes, five or six to be exact.

First I would break up some parts into classes. The two main classes I am thinking of are a simple `Die` class that is simply an immutable `Die` that when created sets the die value to a random number between 1 and 6. Once you create the `Die` object it cannot be changed. Your `ThreeDice` class is narrow and is really unnecessary as the three dice should really be a part of the `Player` object (next class) as a simple array of 3 `Die` objects and as an array of `Die` objects we can sort the dice from low to high.

A sample of a “Die” class is below:

```
Public final class Die implements Comparable<Die>
{
  private int dieNumber;

  // default constructor  
  public Die()
  {
     RollDie();
  }

  public int GetDieNumber()
  {
    return dieNumber;
  }

  public int compareTo(Die otherDie)
  {
     return this.dieNumber - otherDie.dieNumber;
  }

  private void RollDie()
  {
    dieNumber = 1 + (int)(6 * Math.random());
  }
}
```

The next class to help would be a Player class. The important parts of this class will be a player name, then a `Die` object array (of size 3 in your case) to hold the players random dice. In this class you could also have methods to get the total value of the 3 dice, along with a method/variable to get the extra points the user gets if the 3 dice are the same number, if there is a pair, etc. Here we can take advantage of the sorting of the dice array from low to high when the dice array is created. This will make checking for straights easier.

A Player class example is below.

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player>
{
  private String playerName;
  private Die[] diceArray;
  private int diceTotal = 0;
  private int extraPoints = 0;
  private int overallTotal = 0;
  private String extraPointsString = "";

  public Player(String inName, Die[] inDiceArray)
  {
    playerName = inName;
    diceArray = inDiceArray;
    SetDiceTotals();
  }

  public String GetPlayerName()
  {
    return playerName;
  }

  public int GetExtraPoints()
  {
    return extraPoints;
  }

  public int GetDiceTotal()
  {
    return diceTotal;
  }

  public int GetOverallTotal()
  {
    return overallTotal;
  }

  public String GetExtraPointsString()
  {
    return extraPointsString;
  }

  public Die[] GetDiceArray()
  {
    return diceArray;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String playerString = playerName + " Dice values: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++)
    {
      if (i < (diceArray.length - 1))
        playerString = playerString + diceArray[i].GetDieNumber() + ", ";
      else
        playerString = playerString + diceArray[i].GetDieNumber();
    }
    playerString = playerString + " Total: " + GetDiceTotal();
    playerString = playerString + " - Special Points added: " + GetExtraPoints() + " for having " + GetExtraPointsString();
    return playerString + "  Total Points: " + GetOverallTotal();
  }

  public int compareTo(Player otherPlayer)
  {
    int thisTotal = this.GetDiceTotal() + this.GetExtraPoints();
    int otherTotal = otherPlayer.GetDiceTotal() + otherPlayer.GetExtraPoints();
    return otherTotal - thisTotal;
  }

  // private internal method to set dice totals, extra points and extra points string
  private void SetDiceTotals()
  {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++)
    {
      total = total + diceArray[i].GetDieNumber();
    }
    diceTotal = total;

    if (is3OfAKind())
    {
      extraPoints = 60;
      extraPointsString = "Three of a Kind";
    }
    else
    {
      if (isPair())
      {
        extraPoints = 40;
        extraPointsString = "Pair";
      }
      else
      {
        if (isStraight())
        {
          extraPoints = 20;
          extraPointsString = "Straight";
        }
        else
        {
          extraPoints = 0;
          extraPointsString = "All die are different";
        }
      }
    }
    overallTotal = extraPoints + diceTotal;
  }

  private boolean is3OfAKind()
  {
    if (diceArray[0].GetDieNumber() == diceArray[1].GetDieNumber() &&
        diceArray[0].GetDieNumber() == diceArray[2].GetDieNumber())
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  private boolean isPair()
  {
    if (diceArray[0].GetDieNumber() == diceArray[1].GetDieNumber() ||
        diceArray[0].GetDieNumber() == diceArray[2].GetDieNumber() ||
        diceArray[1].GetDieNumber() == diceArray[2].GetDieNumber() )
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  // this method needs to have the diceArray sorted from low to high
  private boolean isStraight()
  {
    if (diceArray[1].GetDieNumber() == (diceArray[0].GetDieNumber() + 1) &&
        diceArray[2].GetDieNumber() == (diceArray[1].GetDieNumber() + 1) )
      return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then, since you want to keep totals for all the rounds, I figure you may need a `Round` class. This class will consist of an array of `Player` objects for a round. Also a round number, total points of the round from all players, an average of points for the round and a string to indicate which player won the round.

A Round class example is below.

```
public class Round
{
  private Player[] playerArray;
  private int roundNumber = 0;
  private int totalPointsForRound = 0;
  private double roundAveragePoints = 0;
  private String roundWinnerName = "";

  public Round(int inRoundNumber, Player[] inPlayerArray)
  {
    playerArray = inPlayerArray;
    roundNumber = inRoundNumber;
    totalPointsForRound = SetAllPointsForRound();
    roundAveragePoints = SetAveragePoints();
    roundWinnerName = SetRoundWinnerName();
  }

  public int GetTotalPointsForRound()
  {
    return totalPointsForRound;
  }

  public double GetAveragePointsForRound()
  {
    return roundAveragePoints;
  }

  public String GetRoundWinnerName()
  {
    return roundWinnerName;
  }

  public Player[] GetPlayerArray()
  {
    return playerArray;
  }

  public int GetRoundNumber()
  {
    return roundNumber;
  }

  private String SetRoundWinnerName()
  {
    // sort the array from high to low - if the first two total are equal then its a tie
    Player[] tempArray = playerArray;
    Arrays.sort(tempArray);
    if (tempArray[0].GetOverallTotal() == tempArray[1].GetOverallTotal())
      return "Tie";
    if (tempArray[0].GetOverallTotal() > tempArray[1].GetOverallTotal())
      return tempArray[0].GetPlayerName();
    return "Unknown Winner???";
  }

  private double SetAveragePoints()
  {
    double totalPoints = GetTotalPointsForRound();
    double average = totalPoints/playerArray.length;
    return Math.round(average*100.0)/100.0;
  }

  private int SetAllPointsForRound()
  {
    int allPoints = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.length; i++)
    {
      allPoints = allPoints + playerArray[i].GetOverallTotal();
    }
    return allPoints;
  }
}
```

Then since you want to keep totals for all the players, you may want to make a small `PlayerTotals` class. This class will simply consist of a player name, total wins for all rounds and total points for all rounds. Keep in mind these are totals for ALL rounds not for a single round as each `Player` object in the `Round's` `playerArray` will contain totals for that particular round.

A PlayerTotals class example is below

```
public class PlayerTotals implements Comparable<PlayerTotals>
{
  String playerName;
  int totalWins = 0;
  int totalPoints = 0;

  public PlayerTotals(String inPlayerName)
  {
    playerName = inPlayerName;
  }

  public int GetTotalPoints()
  {
    return totalPoints;
  }

  public void SetTotalPoints(int inPoints)
  {
    totalPoints = inPoints;
  }

  public int GetTotalWins()
  {
    return totalWins;
  }

  public void SetTotalWins(int inWins)
  {
    totalWins = inWins;
  }

  public int compareTo(PlayerTotals otherPlayerTotals)
  {
    int thisTotalPoints = this.GetTotalPoints();
    int otherTotalPoints = otherPlayerTotals.GetTotalPoints();
    return otherTotalPoints - thisTotalPoints;
  }

}
```

Then two more classes which you could actually combine into one class. One is a static `GameUtils` class that helps do some global things like: `GetPlayerArray`, this method gets an array of `Player` objects. Each `Player` object will contain an array of the 3 dice each player rolled. This dice array will be sorted from low to high. This is the method that gets your initial random rolls for each player for each round. Also here we can `GetPlayerOverallWins` where we can loop through all rounds and total up how many wins each player had. A method called `GetTotalTies` to get the total number of ties from all the rounds. And a method `GetPlayerOverallPoints` to get a total of all players points from all rounds. Also here I placed your prompts for the user to enter the number of players and number of rounds with a check to make sure the user input is valid.

A GameUtils example is below:

```
public final class GameUtils
{
  public static Player[] GetPlayerArray(int numOfPlayers, int numOfDice)
  {
    Player[] playerArray = new Player[numOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++)
    {
      Die[] diceArray = new Die[numOfDice];
      for (int j = 0; j < numOfDice; j++)
      {
        diceArray[j] = new Die();
      }
      Arrays.sort(diceArray);
      playerArray[i] = new Player("Player " + (i + 1), diceArray);
    }
    return playerArray;
  }

  public static int GetNumberOfPlayers(Scanner input)
  {
    return GetValidInteger("Please input number of players (greater than 0) --> ", input);
  }

  public static int GetNumberOfRounds(Scanner input)
  {
    return GetValidInteger("Please input number of rounds (greater than 0) --> ", input);
  }

  private static int GetValidInteger(String prompt, Scanner input)
  {
    boolean done = false;
    int validInt = -1;
    String userInput = "";
    while (!done)
    {
      System.out.print(prompt);
      userInput = input.nextLine();
      try
      {
        validInt = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        done = true;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input: " + userInput + " Try again!");
      }
    }
    return validInt;
  }

  public static int GetPlayerOverallWins(String playerName, Round[] allRounds)
  {
    int totalWins = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allRounds.length; i++)
    {
      Round curRound = allRounds[i];
      String roundWinner = curRound.GetRoundWinnerName();
      if (playerName.equals(roundWinner))
      {
        totalWins++;
      }
    }
    return totalWins;
  }

  public static int GetTotalTies(Round[] allRounds)
  {
    int totalTies = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allRounds.length; i++)
    {
      Round curRound = allRounds[i];
      String roundWinner = curRound.GetRoundWinnerName();
      if (roundWinner.equals("Tie"))
      {
        totalTies++;
      }
    }
    return totalTies;
  }

  public static int GetPlayerOverallPoints(String player, Round[] allRounds)
  {
    int totalPoints = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allRounds.length; i++)
    {
      Round curRound = allRounds[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < curRound.GetPlayerArray().length; j++)
      {
        Player curPlayer = curRound.GetPlayerArray()[j];
        if (player.equals(curPlayer.GetPlayerName()))
        {
          totalPoints = totalPoints + curPlayer.GetOverallTotal();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return totalPoints;
  }

}
```

Lastly a `DiceGame` class with a main entry to put it all together. A dice game class will consist of global variables `numberOfPlayers`. `numberOfRounds`, `numberOfDice`, and a `playerArray` to use for each round, then an array of `Rounds` to hold all the rounds for totaling after all the rounds have been run. The example below starts by setting a loop for the number of rounds, in this loop we create all the players and dice values for them then save the round information into a new `Round` object then place each  new `Round` object into an array. Then the results from the current round is output to the user. Once the loop on the number of rounds finishes, we should then have an array of `Round` objects. Here is where the `PlayerTotals` class helps as we can create another array of `PlayerTotals` objects for all rounds. This uses some methods from `GameUtils` and these methods could just a well be placed into this main class. After all player totals for all rounds have been added up, the results are output to the user.

Main DiceGame class example:

```
public class DiceGame
{
  public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  static int numberOfPlayers;
  static int numberOfRounds;
  static int numberOfDice = 3;
  static Player[] playerArray;
  static Round[] allRounds;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    numberOfPlayers = GameUtils.GetNumberOfPlayers(input);
    numberOfRounds = GameUtils.GetNumberOfRounds(input);

    System.out.println("");
    allRounds = new Round[numberOfRounds];
    // for each round - we want to create players with the proper number of random dice
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++)
    {
      // get an array of players with random dice
      playerArray = GameUtils.GetPlayerArray(numberOfPlayers, numberOfDice);
      Round currentRound = new Round(i, playerArray);
      allRounds[i] = currentRound;
      // print the results of this round
      System.out.println("Round " + (i + 1) + " Results - Winner is: " + currentRound.GetRoundWinnerName()
      + " -- Average score for this round: " + currentRound.GetAveragePointsForRound());
      for (int j = 0; j < playerArray.length; j++)
      {
        System.out.println(playerArray[j].toString());
      }
      System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }

    // now get totals for all rounds
    // first create an array of PlayerTotals
    PlayerTotals[] allPlayersTotals = new PlayerTotals[numberOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
    {
      PlayerTotals curPlayer = new PlayerTotals(playerArray[i].GetPlayerName());
      curPlayer.SetTotalPoints(GameUtils.GetPlayerOverallPoints(curPlayer.playerName, allRounds));
      curPlayer.SetTotalWins(GameUtils.GetPlayerOverallWins(curPlayer.playerName, allRounds));
      allPlayersTotals[i] = curPlayer;
    }

    // print the overall results
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(" -- Overall Results --");
    System.out.println("Ties: " + GameUtils.GetTotalTies(allRounds));
    Arrays.sort(allPlayersTotals);
    PlayerTotals curPlayer;

    for (int i = 0; i < allPlayersTotals.length; i++)
    {
      curPlayer = allPlayersTotals[i];
      System.out.println(curPlayer.playerName + " Won " + curPlayer.totalWins + " times - Total Points: " + curPlayer.totalPoints);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope these make things easier. Good Luck!